# ASP.NET WebApi authentication with AngularJS

Tags: authentication, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I need to restrict my WebApi service to only logged in users. The clients that will be hitting the service will be mobile so I am using CORS.

I am looking for the simplest way to implement authentication. I am currently using SimpleMembership. I am also using $ngResource for my service calls.

Comment: MVC5 has changed the authentication module. `SimpleMembership` is no longer there. Please consider using `OWIN` and `Katana` in your application.