# angularjs WebAPI authentication project template

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

I would like to develop a web site (app) using AngularJs and WebAPI, but will require users to create a profile and login or use an oauth provider. I can see many resources on the web for it, what I can't find is a visual studio projects template that takes care of all the plumbing. Anyone aware of such a template out there?

I love John Pappa's Hottowel SPA template but it does not have authentication baked in, and does not seem to have been updated in a long time.

I hate "plumbing" so I would appreciate any help that will get me straight into building the logic of my app.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some project template available for example [ng.Net.Template](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/48d928e3-9b5c-4faf-b46f-d6baa7d9886c?SRC=VSIDE),

But Instead of looking for the template I'll recommend you develop your authentication module so that you have full control over it. It is fairly easy to implement, please see the this answer to understand in details : [ASP.NET WebApi authentication with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348500/asp-net-webapi-authentication-with-angularjs?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks Totalo, the ng.Net Template looks like it will work great. I really have no interest in having full control over authentication, I'm quite happy using something that works. I would rather spend my energy in making the functionality of my website great